# Mysql 5.7 use IF THEN or CASE WHEN in GENERATED columns

Tags: mysql

I'm looking a way to create a virtual column in my Mysql DB https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html with a condition.

The idea is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Contact` 
(`id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`companyName` VARCHAR(255),
`firstName` VARCHAR(255),
`lastName` VARCHAR(255),
`fullName` VARCHAR(255) AS (IF personType='LEGAL_PERSON' THEN `companyName` ELSE CONCAT(lastName,' ',firstName) END IF) VIRTUAL,
`personType` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'NATURAL_PERSON' NOT NULL);
```

I didn't find any example using conditions in virtual columns. Is that possible? Any hint on another smart way to do that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you generated the column with the condition using select? something like `SELECT *,IF(personType = 'LEGAL_PERSON',companyName,CONCAT(lastName,' ',firstName)) VIRTUAL from Contact`

Comment: @RyanTan It's not always about ease. Generated column _can_ be needed. It encapsulates a certain information in a table to be centralized.

Comment: my mistake, forgive my ignorance. it would be interesting to know this too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it works. It's just that [`IF`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-function.aspx) here should be a function, not a keyword so the syntax is different as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867292/mysql-5-7-use-if-then-or-case-when-in-generated-columns#comment100283591_56867292). Try:

```
CREATE TABLE `Contact` (
    `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `companyName` VARCHAR(255),
    `firstName` VARCHAR(255),
    `lastName` VARCHAR(255),
    `fullName` VARCHAR(255) AS (
        IF(
            personType = 'LEGAL_PERSON', -- condition
            `companyName`, -- value if true
            CONCAT(lastName, ' ', firstName) -- value if false
            )
        ) VIRTUAL,
    `personType` VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT 'NATURAL_PERSON' NOT NULL
);
```